# CSS - Customising heading settings

Tags: css

The basic idea is that I have a sidebar div tag that I have been tweaking with the CSS, and I want to do everything in the same place:

```
.sidebar{
    border: solid;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    width:200px;
}

.sidebar h2{text-decoration:underline}
```

This is what the code looks like right now and it technically works but it looks like bad practice to me and I want to add the bottom bit that changes h2 to the main chunk on the top which has everything else in it but I don't know how to incorporate it.

I imagine that this is fairly straight forward and I'm just missing something.

Comment: This isn't bad practice, this is how CSS is supposed to be written.

Comment: Oh that's odd. I expected it to all fit nicely into the one set of curly brackets. Well thanks I guess!

Comment: @LukaszMedza You say you want everything inside one set of curly brackets...until you have 20 different elements you're styling, which are all nested inside a div. Then you'll be glad for the separation of elements and the cascading nature of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're thinking about is using a CSS preprocessor that allows you to combine multiple child classes into one big class, giving it a nicer look and feel, like this:

```
.sidebar{
    border: solid;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    width:200px;

  h2
  {
    text-decoration:underline;
  }
}
```

For this you can use LESS. More info on it here: [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/)